# How to compare a Python float with a Mysql decimal in python?

Tags: python, mysql, compare, decimal

I'm storing price as decimal(8,2) in mysql and I need to compare equality with a float in python.

Say I have `4.28` in database and `select` returns `price = (Decimal(4.28),)`. I convert it to python decimal by `decimal.Decimal(price[0])`, but `decimal.Decimal(price[0]) == 4.28` returns false.

Is there a way to compare equality directly other than comparing the difference with a small number, i.e.
`decimal.Decimal(price[0]) - decimal.Decimal(4.28) < 0.01`

Thanks

Comment: `price[0]` is already decimal. Why are you trying to convert it to decimal again like `decimal.Decimal(price[0])`? Because `decimal.Decimal(decimal.Decimal(4.28))` returned `Decimal('4.28000000000000024868995751603506505489349365234375')` in my laptop.

Comment: @ozgur `price[0]` is a value return from database (using mysqldb) which is not Python decimal, it literally `Decimal(4.28)`

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no other way to compare float representations of numbers for equality, but there are ways to make it practical:

```
decimal.Decimal(price[0]) - decimal.Decimal(4.28) < 0.01
```

should really be:

```
abs(decimal.Decimal(price[0]) - decimal.Decimal(4.28)) < 0.01
```

You can abstract the comparison:

```
def almost_equal(a, b, epsilon=1e-5):
    """returns true is the absolute value of the difference between a & b 
    is less than epsilon i/e a & b are almost equal, False otherwise
    """
    return abs(a - b) < epsilon
```

Comment: good pick for the `abs()` part. I'm only going to use it once, so probably no need to make a method for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert what you're *comparing to* to a decimal:

```
decimal.Decimal('4.28') == decimal.Decimal(price[0])
```